# Angular 11 on Plesk with server side rendering/angular universal

Tags: node.js, server-side-rendering, plesk, angular-universal, angular11

At the moment I try to get my Plesk server running with angular universal.

I've installed nodeJs and configured this as followed:
Node.js-versie 12.4.0
Document root /httpdocs
Applicatiemodus production
URL van toepassing http://+domain
Application root /httpdocs   open
Startup server/main.js
variables none

- My browser files are copied in the httpdocs.
- My server folder is copied in the httpdocs.

Server side rendering will not be executed..

As I'm searching for many hours now I've tried to changed the next suggestions:

Server.ts:
Replace:

```
if (moduleFilename === __filename || moduleFilename.includes('iisnode')) {
  run();
}
```

With:

```
run();
```

-> no success

Change application root to a new file called server.js and copied the following code in it:

```
const app = require('./app');
const http = require('http');

http.createServer(app).listen(process.env.PORT);
```

Restart nodejs

-> No success (as expected)

It seems like Plesk/nodeJs won't start the express server or reach it (no log errors...)

Is there anyone who has had the same issues and resolved it?

Thanks in advance for any help or answering!
Kind regards,
R

Comment: I am having a similar problem. Server operating system Windows and plesk panel available. When I run my Angular Universal project, I get an "Internal Server Error". The same project does not have this problem on the Linux server. Did you solve your problem?

Comment: Having the same problem, did you manage to solve it?

Comment: No, unfortunately this is still an issue. There is one thing i did not try and i don't have the time to experiment with it.. 

In you're server.ts there is this line:
`const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/browser');`

Delete dist/ and try to build and serve it on the server.. 

Maybe this is the solution to production serving.

Please let me know ;)